# snowflake unload to S3 as parquet has no column names nor correct datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dask, parquet

The following produces a parquet file in S3:

```
USE DATABASE SANDBOX;
USE SCHEMA SANDBOX;

CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_parquet_format 
  TYPE = parquet;

COPY INTO @bla/x_
FROM (
    SELECT 
        TOP 10
        xxx AS "id",
    FROM table
)
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = my_parquet_format)
OVERWRITE=TRUE;
```

Alas the column "id" arrives as _COL_0 and the data type is object when I use:

```
s3_path = 's3://ddd/dddd__0_0_0.snappy.parquet'
df = pd.read_parquet(s3_path, engine='pyarrow')
```

or Dask. I tried:

```
USE DATABASE SANDBOX;
USE SCHEMA SANDBOX;

CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_parquet_format 
  TYPE = parquet;

COPY INTO @bla/x_
FROM (
    SELECT 
        TOP 10
        xxx AS "id",
    FROM table
)
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = my_parquet_format)
OVERWRITE=TRUE HEADER=TRUE;
```

as some suggested but it produces a corrupt parquet file. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is this really a pandas/dask issue, or can you tell whether the parquet file is indeed incorrect (so the problem lies solely with snowflake)?

Comment: Thanks. What would be the way to assess this? Can one open parquet files somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changes the above as follows. This enforces some schema and pulls though columns names. Guess one cannot enforce panda's category format?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_parquet_format 
  TYPE = parquet;

COPY INTO @bla/x_
FROM (
    SELECT 
        TOP 10
        xxx::SMALLINT AS "id",
    FROM table
)
file_format = (type = 'parquet')
header = true overwrite = true;
```

Comment: I don't believe arrow ever loads to pandas categoricals. With fastparquet you can, but if the data didn't originate with pandas, you must specify an extra argument.